# Numpy extract values along a dimension for a given point

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have an (N0, N1, N2, N3, ...) dimensional ndarray A. I want all points in the array for dimension 0, for a given index x1, x2, x3 ... of dimensions 1, 2, 3 and so forth. All the indexes x are stored in a list l. So what I want is

```
A[:, l[0], l[1], ...]
```

However, I want to do that without explicitly writing out the elements of the list? I am looking for a functionality like

`A[:, *l]`.

Here's an example for the 3 dimensional case.

```
> a = np.arange(8).reshape(2,2,2) 
array([[[0, 1],
    [2, 3]],

   [[4, 5],
    [6, 7]]])
```

Suppose l = [0, 0]. I want to get

```
> a[:,l[0],l[1]]
array([0, 4])
```

Without writing out l[0], l[1]. The reason is that the array I am working with has many dimensions and writing out the indices makes the code  unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your goal right, I'd build up a tuple.

```
A[(slice(None),)+tuple(ll)]
```

e.g.

```
In [121]: A=np.ones((2,3,4,5))
In [122]: ll=[1,2,3]
In [123]: A[:,1,2,3]
Out[123]: array([ 1.,  1.])
In [124]: (slice(None),)+tuple(ll)
Out[124]: (slice(None, None, None), 1, 2, 3)
In [125]: A[(slice(None),)+tuple(ll)]
Out[125]: array([ 1.,  1.])
```

There are some helper functions and classes that facilitate things like this (`ix_`, `r_`, etc), but it all comes down to creating a tuple, something that will be passed to: `A.__getitem__(*atuple)`

```
A[i,j,k] <=> A[(i,j,k)] <=> A.__getitem__((i,j,k))
```

with helpers:

```
In [139]: np.index_exp[:]+tuple(ll)
Out[139]: (slice(None, None, None), 1, 2, 3)
In [147]: (np.s_[:],)+tuple(ll)
Out[147]: (slice(None, None, None), 1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I want.